# Confirm login of site with scrape

Tags: python-requests, lxml

I am trying to login to my gym and scrape the data so I can setup automatic login/reservations for the future. I am very new to python, I have tried a few things and I think this is the closest. I found a great example online but having issues. I think the login is failing making the code not access the correct page to scrape. I used XPath helper and it confirmed my xpath was correct but my result is blank []
Please see below.. any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
import requests
from lxml import html

USERNAME = "*****"
PASSWORD = "*****"
LOGIN_URL = "https://www.lafitness.com/Pages/login.aspx"
URL = "https://www.lafitness.com/Pages/RacquetballReservation.aspx"

def main():
    session_requests = requests.session()

# Get login csrf token
    result = session_requests.get(LOGIN_URL)
    tree = html.fromstring(result.text)
    authenticity_token = list(set(tree.xpath("//input[@name='__CSRFTOKEN']/@value")))[0]

# Create payload
    payload = {
        "ctl00$MainContent$Login1$txtUser": USERNAME,
        "ctl00$MainContent$Login1$txtPassword": PASSWORD,
        "__CSRFTOKEN": authenticity_token
     }

# Perform login
    result = session_requests.post(LOGIN_URL, data = payload, headers = dict(referer = LOGIN_URL))

# Scrape url
    result = session_requests.get(URL, headers = dict(referer = URL))
    tree = html.fromstring(result.content)
    bucket_names = tree.xpath('//*[@id="ddlDates"]')

    ok = result.ok

    print(ok, bucket_names)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have looked up several items trying to do this but have been unsuccessful. I added the result.ok to see if it's connecting correctly, which it says it does, but I have read just because it says positive doesn't mean the website logged in correctly.

Thanks for any help/suggestions!